# Error writing a video in Matlab R2015b with audio

Tags: matlab, audio, video

I'm writing a function to put some sound from an mp3 in a video and I'm getting an error if I try to save a `mp4` file. If it is an `avi` file it is ok. The thing is that `avi` will be much larger so. The error is:

> Error using vision.VideoFileWriter/step Too many input arguments;
>   expected 1 (in addition to the object handle), got 2. Error in
>   p10_see_only_positive
>                   step(videoFWriter, im, au);

Here is my code:

```
function p10_see_only_positive(str)
% function to put audio and video together

video_str = sprintf('./videos/%s.mp4', str);

% found out how many frames does the video have
vid = VideoReader(strcat('./videos/', str, '.mp4'));

% check input
if exist(video_str,'file') == 2
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_str);
    [y, fs] = audioread(sprintf('./videos/%s.mp3', str));

    val = fs/vid.FrameRate;
else
    error('Input file not exist');
end

% prepare video
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter(sprintf('./videos/final_%s.mp4', str), ...
    'FrameRate', vid.FrameRate, 'FileFormat', 'MPEG4', ...
    'AudioInputPort', true);

for ii = 1:10000
    im = cap.read;
    au = y(val*(ii - 1) + 1: val*ii, :);

    if isempty(im)
        warning('End of file');
        break;
    else
        step(videoFWriter, im, au);
    end
end

fprintf('Video: %d\n', nvid);

release(videoFWriter);
end
```

This is the VideoFileWriter in `mp4`:

```
val = 

  Properties:
          Filename: './videos/final_jornal_all_1.mp4'
        FileFormat: 'MPEG4'                          
         FrameRate: 25                               
    FileColorSpace: 'RGB'                            
           Quality: 75
```

and now the `avi` one:

```
val = 

  Properties:
           Filename: './videos/final_jornal_all_1.mp4'
         FileFormat: 'AVI'                            
     AudioInputPort: true                             
          FrameRate: 25                               
    AudioCompressor: 'None (uncompressed)'            
    VideoCompressor: 'None (uncompressed)'            
     FileColorSpace: 'RGB'
```

I guess the `mp4` format does not recognize the audio input.

Any workarounds?

Comment: What MATLAB version do you use?

Comment: I've edited the title, thanks, it's R2015b.